# Finding which lte bands my Samsung galaxy tab supports without rooting?

Tags: 4g, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-3

Everything is in the title It’s not about the bands currently in use but those my device can supports (my cell phone provider is refusing to let me access full of their supportted bands)…

As I don t know the target region of my device, the only way to know is to find which ones are supported in practice.

Comment: While the question looks like on-topic, the question is a bit terse as of currently written. It'd be better if you can [edit] and add a clear example for your specific case, which device (the title says: Samsung Galaxy Tab, but the tag says: Samsung Galaxy S3?), the current LTE bands your device support, and the theoretical LTE bands the device should support.

Comment: @AndrewT. My device is in tags. I have no idea about what bands my device supports in theory. Really… Everything I know is in the question. I’m failing to see what I can add.

Comment: I assume you meant Galaxy Tab S3 (tablet), not Galaxy S3 (smartphone). Also, it's preferable to do some researches first so that the question is clear and unanswerable from the beginning. I made an edit for you this time, feel free to [edit] and improve it further :)